# FQL Get All Comments and Likes On User Photos

Tags: sql, facebook-fql

I would like to retrieve all comments and like on user photos. It shouldn't be specific album  photos. I tried something like this, but it did not work.

```
SELECT fromid, user_likes, comments FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT object_id FROM photo
  WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid FROM album
    WHERE owner=me()))
```

Comment: What are the table structures?

Comment: Table structures? This is about facebook, not my specific table.

Comment: My bad. I thought facebook tables had a structure too

Comment: I tried to say, if it was my own database, I would explain all the coloumns by name before giving SQL example. But, it is FQL question and that's why I already assume that you know about facebook table structure at least better than me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following queries:

```
SELECT fromid, user_likes, **text** FROM comment
WHERE object_id IN 
( 
    SELECT object_id FROM photo
    WHERE aid IN ( 
        SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me() 
    )
)
```